# How to allow the children component to use a wrapper when the parent component uses @ContentChildren query

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

The actual problem is more complicated, but here is the simplified version.

I have a parent component called `app-grid`, and child component called `app-grid-row`. `app-grid-row` has a `templateRef` which contains the columns.

In `app-grid`, I need to use `@ContentChildren` to query all the `app-grid-row` content projection. I can't use `<ng-content>` because I need to modify the way they are rendered.

`app-grid.component.ts`:

```
export class GridComponent {
  
  @ContentChildren(GridRowComponent)
  public rows: QueryList<GridRowComponent>;

  ........

}
```

`app-grid.component.html`:

```
// Again, this is a simplified version

<div class="row" *ngFor="let row of rows">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="row.templateRef></ng-container>
</div>
```

This works fine:

```
<app-grid>
  <app-grid-row>...</app-grid-row>
  <app-grid-row>...</app-grid-row>
</app-grid>
```

What I want to do is to have a wrapper component that wraps all the `app-grid-row` because they can get really long.

With a wrapper component, this doesn't work:

```
<app-grid>
  <app-wrapper></app-wrapper>
</app-grid>
```

Where `app-wrapper.component.html` contains all the `app-grid-row`.

This is the link to the demo: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3gjtsm)

Answer (score 1):

I think this can't be done as is, when we check the description of the ContentChildren annotation, it says :

`Does not retrieve elements or directives that are in other components' templates, since a component's template is always a black box to its ancestors.`

https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren#description

So I guess you should add some kind of binding or logic in your wrapper ?

Comment: Yep, you are right. It is stated that it can't be done: `Does not retrieve elements or directives that are in other components' templates, since a component's template is always a black box to its ancestors.`

Comment: I think one of solution would be create a based class which promises to give a list of the `app-grid-row`. Then any wrappers need to extend this based class in order to wrap `app-grid-row`. The `app-grid` can now query for the based class and get the  reference to the `app-grid-row` from it. But this is not ideal.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, extending another class would not be ideal. What about some simple binding ? Also, if the goal is to alter the display of the items, you could try some directive ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "simple binding"? Do you mean something like using `@Input, @Output` to pass around the data?

Comment: The goal is to not only alter the display of the items, but also calculate each column's width. It's something quite complex, but from high level, we want to use this `app-grid` component to replace the CSS grid. The reason is that CSS grid doesn't support a dynamic size for both lower and upper bound at the same time. Eg: `grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));`. Note the `250px` magic number. This is troublesome because content that is wider than 250px will overflow it.

Comment: Yes I meant Input and Output